# My new setup website Directs to /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: domains, web-hosting, wordpress, dns, cpanel

I have many domains set up in cPanel. I just added a new website and it keeps directing me to /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi.

Why?? Please can you explain why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: There's a number of different reasons why this might be occurring, the question marked as a duplicate contain some, and this cPanel forum thread contains others:  https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/domain-redirecting-to-cgi-sys-defaultwebpage-cgi.139597/page-5 You'll need to contact your provider should those not be helpful since there are too many possibilities for us to help troubleshoot this for you.